# Using multiple apps to get a pseudo-Dynamically-Linked-Library

Tags: ios

I've read that all libraries on iOS have to be statically linked.  However, I recently came across [this post](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html), which details how to launch one app from another app, and to pass parameters from the first app to the second.  If the second were to preform some calculations, then re-launch the first at some point and pass the results of those calculations, **wouldn't that essentially be a dll?**  Would apps be rejected from the AppStore if they follow that workflow?  If so, then what's the point of allowing apps to open each other if those apps are going to be rejected anyway?  I feel like there's something I'm just not getting here.  **Is my understanding of static vs dynamic libraries incorrect?**  Or am I miss-understanding Apple's philosophies for what is acceptable and what isn't?  Or are there just some inconsistencies in those philosophies?

Comment: You could launch another app for that, but that wouldn't be the primary use case of the app you're opening - it has to do something useful on its own. If you submit an app to Apple that would just be used like that it wouldn't get to the store...

Comment: @Wain: Ah, so you're saying any app that doesn't do anything **on it's own, without support from other apps** would get rejected.  Okay, I guess that answers my question - thanks.